# Can / should we answer primary opinion based and closed questions by comment?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As we know, most sites here reject primary opinion based questions, but sometimes we may find awesome opinion based questions containing useful information in comments and answers.

The problem is: Can / should I answer that by comments? If so, am I doing wrong because of encouraging opinion based questions? What is the stance of this site for the situation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, we shouldn't feed users who post off-topic questions with answers, in either way. The end result is that they get what they want, they don't care if it is an answer or a comment.

What we should do is educate the user to understand how to adjust his question to be on-topic for the site, if possible.

[My short todo list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/993547) for such questions:

- cast a down vote
- vote to close (flag to close if you're under 3K rep)
- comment and explain why their question is bad and how to fix it, use the tour, the help, maybe even a chat session

What you choose to do is entirely up to you. Maybe you choose to comment first, then after a while when OP didn't constructively participate, cast a down vote or close vote.

Comment: I may be mis-reading the question here but I think it is about questions asked ***in*** Comments and Answers that would off-topic ***if*** they were asked as Question.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a question in an answer then I think you should first think about whether you can edit it to make a statement that is still part of a direct answer to the original question.

If you cannot then I think you should either edit it out as irrelevant, or downvote it, perhaps with a comment to that effect.

I think comments should only be used to help clarify questions and answers, so anything that is going off on a tangent should not be answered within comments.  Instead, I think you should comment to suggest they ask a new question, but if it seems like that would just lead to something that is off-topic then warn that it might be something better raised in chat.